# is it ok to study older version for aws solutions architect, spesifically learning 001 from the books to prepare for 002?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to study aws solutions architect, is it ok to still study material 001 from the books to prepare for the new version?? New version is 002. Specifically from books on amazon store.I was planning on buying some books.The material shoudnt be too diffrent??

Comment: This is good place to ask about aws certs: https://old.reddit.com/r/AWSCertifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it really does not matter as both share 95% of the same content. There are many good resources out there for it but do be aware the 001 exam is soon due to be deprecated so will not be available to sit (you'll still keep the cert).

Answer (score 0):

i have cleared almost all AWS certifications.. including that of Architect.. I would say that yes sure u can .. there is not much of difference.